# Shopify GraphQL using fetch API, returns empty json, no errors

Tags: graphql, shopify, fetch-api

Trying to just fetch the name of my store in a React component using the Fetch API and GraphQL endpoint of Shopify.

I created a Shopify store, gave permissions to the Storefront API and crafted this in my `componentDidMount()` section of my react component.

```
let query = '{ shop { name } }';
console.log(JSON.stringify(query));

fetch('https://myStoreName.myshopify.com/api/graphql', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/graphql",
            "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": "<My API Key>"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(query),
    })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log('fetched');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
  });
```

My console log output:

```
"{ shop { name } }"
App.js:21 fetched
App.js:22 {}
```

I'm not even getting an error, makes me think it's going through possibly? 
But can't find my shop's name in this query?

I think overall I don't know best practices to craft a GraphQL query in Javascript.
Do I make a large string or just a normal,  JSON to represent it?

*Also I'm trying not to use a graphQL client library at the moment, and just to use fetch API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't read the response the `fetch` call resolves to directly like that. Instead, you should call whatever method is appropriate for the mime type you're fetching. From the Mozilla docs:

> Once a Response is retrieved, there are a number of methods available to define what the body content is and how it should be handled.

For JSON, you call the `json` method. You can see more examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). That means your code should look more like this:

```
fetch(...)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(console.log)
```

Also, please bear in mind that you don't need to `stringify` your query. You should probably use the `application/json` content type (which is standard, I believe) and wrap your query inside an object like this.

```
body: { query },
```

Then if you have variables, these can be included in the same object:

```
body: { query, variables }
```

Comment: d'oh! I forgot how promises work there for a minute and realized i had `stringify()`and not `json()` appended! Thank you! And I'll def. why does mine only work when `body: query` and not when `body: { query }`, is that because I have it as `query { ... }` ?

Comment: oops sorry just noticed you're using the `application/graphql` mimetype... it'll work if you change that to `application/json`. I'll update my answer